# How to create dfp native ad unit id for android

Tags: android, admob, double-click-advertising

i want to create DFP native unit id for my android app. I searched alot but unable to find best way to create working dfp native unitId . if someone know then please help me

Answer (score 2):

Detail implementation of native ads for DFP is described here : 
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/drx-custom-rendering-android/#0

and

https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/android/native

DFP is best for showing native ads, and the time taken to reflect the changes on the client side is like 3-5minutes, which is amazing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test your implementation you can use `/6499/example/native` which will always return an ad for standard native ad formats (standard content or install ads) and a sample custom ad format with id `10063170`. [See Docs](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/android/native#testing_native_ad_code).

If you want to create a new one it's a little complicated, but there are [instructions](https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/177203) here. Basically you have to log into your [Google Doubleclick for Publishers account](https://www.google.com/dfp) and go to "Inventory" and look for "New Ad Unit".